# Get difference from current GMT time until 9PM gmt

Tags: java, time, jodatime

I'm running a task every minute, i want to print out the difference between the current GMT time and 9PM GMT, i want this to run all the time so once it hits 9PM gmt it'll then reset to 24 hours so its looking for 9PM gmt the next day.

I have the jodatime libary installed

I have tried, this gets the current GMT time?

```
TimeZone gmtTimeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT");
        TimeZone.setDefault(gmtTimeZone);
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(gmtTimeZone);
```

now to get 9 oclock i can get the hour?

```
if(calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY); == 9) {
```

so my question is how do i get from now to 9PM gmt? and format it nicely IE; 16 Hours, 15 minutes and 4 seconds?

Thankyou.

Comment: It will be great if you can also mention what you have tried.

Comment: Hey there! This might help you formulate a strong question https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

This way we can provide better feedback!

Comment: Updated post with what i have already. @AbhishekGarg

Comment: Have you got a particular wish to use Joda-Time? Asking because “Joda-Time is considered to be a largely “finished” project. No major enhancements are planned.” (quote from [the home page](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/)). They recommend “If using Java SE 8, please migrate to `java.time` (JSR-310).” You can if using Java 6 or 7 too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Joda-Time, you can get time until 9 PM GMT using the following helper method:

```
import org.joda.time.DateTimeZone;
import org.joda.time.LocalTime;
import org.joda.time.Period;
import org.joda.time.format.PeriodFormat;
```

```
public static String timeUntil(int hourOfDay, int minuteOfHour) {
    Period period = Period.fieldDifference(LocalTime.now(DateTimeZone.UTC),
                                           new LocalTime(hourOfDay, minuteOfHour))
                          .plusHours(24).normalizedStandard().withDays(0).withMillis(0);
    StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
    PeriodFormat.wordBased(Locale.US).printTo(buf, period);
    return buf.toString();
}
```

*Test*

```
System.out.println(timeUntil(21, 0)); // until 9 pm GMT
System.out.println(timeUntil(22, 0)); // until 10 pm GMT
```

*Sample Output*

```
23 hours, 31 minutes and 48 seconds
31 minutes and 48 seconds
```

Comment: Note that this logic doesn't handle Daylight Savings Time, which isn't an issue for UTC / GMT, but could be if you change to use another time zone.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use Java's `java.time` library methods instead of calendar, if you're using at least Java 8. They are much friendlier, and harder to inadvertantly use wrong.

```
// in a 24 hour clock, 9PM = 21:00
final int ninePM = 21;

OffsetDateTime now = OffsetDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC);
OffsetDateTime next9PM;
if (now.getHour() >= ninePM) {
    next9PM = now.plus(1, ChronoUnit.DAYS)
                 .withHour(ninePM)
                 .truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.HOURS);
} else {
    next9PM = now.withHour(ninePM)
                 .truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.HOURS);
}

return Duration.between(now, next9PM);
```

Comment: Thanks for showing the modern solution. I did a couple of simple tests: it works.